# Find the integral curves of the equation $\frac{a\mathrm{d}x}{(b-c)yz} = \frac{b\mathrm{d}y}{(c-a)zx} = \frac{c\mathrm{d}z}{(a-b)xy}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The equation is:

$$\frac{a\mathrm{d}x}{(b-c)yz} = \frac{b\mathrm{d}y}{(c-a)zx} = \frac{c\mathrm{d}z}{(a-b)xy}$$

We found one integral curve as such $u = (ax^2)/2 + (by^2)/2 + (cz^2)/2 = c$,
but we could not find the other curve.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first two equality you can find the second one. Indeed,

$$\frac{a\mathrm{d}x}{(b-c)yz} = \frac{b\mathrm{d}y}{(c-a)zx} \Rightarrow \frac{a\mathrm{d}x}{(b-c)y} = \frac{b\mathrm{d}y}{(c-a)x}\Rightarrow \frac{ax\mathrm{d}x}{(b-c)} = \frac{by\mathrm{d}y}{(c-a)} (\text{a separable ODE})$$$$\Rightarrow \frac{ax^2}{(b-c)} -\frac{by^2}{(c-a)}=c_2=v(x, y, z).$$